# Woocommerce Issue with 2 emails of same paypal account?

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, paypal-ipn

i noticed that i received an error about "Unpaid order cancelled – time limit reached. Order status changed from Pending Payment to Cancelled."

I know some say that to fix this simply clear out the hold stock option in "inventory" but i am wondering if there might be another issue.

In woocommerce paypal settings, for "paypal email" i have "payment@mycompany.com", for the "receiver email" i have my personal email set "myname@live.com"

On paypal, both of these email addresses are part of the same account but the primary email on paypal is my personal email. Any issues with this?

Answer (score 0):

Make certain that the receiver email and your PayPal Email you are using in WooCommerce is a [confirmed email](https://www.paypal.com/selfhelp/help/article/FAQ1485) on your PayPal Account. If the email is not confirmed then the funds will never go into your PayPal Account. 
[Woothemes PayPal Standard Instructions](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/paypal-standard/)